# Python 3.X micro ORM compatible with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

My application is database heavy (full of very complex queries and stored procedures), it would be too hard and inefficient to write these queries in a lambda way, for this reason I'll have to stick with raw SQL.

So far I found these 2 'micro' ORMs but none are compatible with MSSQL:

**PonyORM**

Supports: SQLite, PostgreSQL, MySQL and Oracle

**Peewee**

Supports: SQLite, PostgreSQL, MySQL and CockroachDB

I know SQLAlchemy supports MSSQL, however it would bee too big for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today - Jan 2020 - it seems that using `pyodbc` is still the way to go for SQL Server + Python if you are not using Django or any other big frameworks.